# How to identify AAB (Split APK) apps without installing / downloading it?

Tags: android, mobile, apk

How to identify if an app published in the Google PlayStore supports AAB (split-apk) or not (without downloading/installing that app)?

Basically, I have a list of applications and want to categorize based on its support for AAB.

PS: I am not an Android Developer, so am not aware of much of the technical aspects.

Comment: go to play store console. Go to that app and check in release section. I can explain in detail if needed.

Comment: @RahulKhatri The thing is that I don't have the access to the play store console for those applications, and, AFAIK an APK is identifiable as AAB/Split APK or a Single APK through play console, only if you are the publisher of that application, which isn't in my case.